# A nice column and row with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, frontend

As I am not really a frontend developer, I am just wondering if someone could assist me with this simple thing, thank you! My request is really simple, the picture below shows what I am trying to do but incapable of doing so due to lack of CSS knowledge.

**Current CSS**

```
.col {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: auto;
    width: 290px;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

**Current HTML**

```
<div id="content-div">
<h2 align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">Welcome back, {{ username }}!</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Account</h2>
        <p>AccountID: {{ accountid }}</p>
        <p>Username: {{ username }}</p>
        <p>Register Date: {{ register_date }}</p>
        <p>Last Login: {{ lastlogin_date }}</p>
        <p>Kills: {{ kills }}</p>
        <p>Deaths: {{ deaths }}</p>
        <p>Money: ${{ money }}</p>
        <p>Score: {{ score }}</p>
        <p>Admin Level: {{ adminlevel }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Items</h2>
        {% for i in items %}
            <p>{{ i.item_name|capitalize }}: {{ i.value }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        {% for i in skills %}
            <p>{{ i.skill_name }}: {{ i.value }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Proposal Layout

[image: Proposal Layout]

Current layout

[image: Current layout]

Comment: Start with bootstrap. Use col-xs-12 col-md-4.  Or if your adventurous try flex box

Comment: Look into CSS grids or flex boxes. There are also plenty of CSS frameworks available so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox is really useful for this, here's a prototype with some comments. If you want to learn more I recommend a tutorial/spec/documentation, such as those provided by MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

```css
.row {
    margin: -1em; /*Negative margin method to set padding between columns*/
    display: flex; /*align-items defaults to stretch, so columns will have the same height*/
}
.col {
  flex: 1 1 0; /*Make all columns the same width*/
  margin: 1em; /*Corresponds to negative margin above*/
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; /*A column with the header on top and info below*/
}
.col > .info {
  flex-grow: 1; /*Info grows to fill the column*/
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-div">
<h2 align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">Welcome back, {{ username }}!</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Account</h2>
        <div class="info">
        <p>AccountID: {{ accountid }}</p>
        <p>Username: {{ username }}</p>
        <p>Register Date: {{ register_date }}</p>
        <p>Last Login: {{ lastlogin_date }}</p>
        <p>Kills: {{ kills }}</p>
        <p>Deaths: {{ deaths }}</p>
        <p>Money: ${{ money }}</p>
        <p>Score: {{ score }}</p>
        <p>Admin Level: {{ adminlevel }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Items</h2>
        <div class="info">
        {% for i in items %}
            <p>{{ i.item_name|capitalize }}: {{ i.value }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <div class="info">
        {% for i in skills %}
            <p>{{ i.skill_name }}: {{ i.value }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, the below code should work to solve your problem.

This is just an illustration, please modify the code per your requirements.

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.child div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .child {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 10px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <div>First</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div>Second</div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div>Third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might break in responsive mode

Comment: @VipinMohanRNair Agreed. For that I would suggest starting with bootstrap. Although the above code can be made mobile responsive with a couple of media queries. Does the OP need mobile view?

Comment: If you dont want to use bootstrap i suggest writing cases using @media screen and (max-width: ***px)

Comment: @VipinMohanRNair just added media queries to support mobile view.

Comment: If i remember correctly wasn't it `@media screen and (max-width ) : `?

Comment: adding screen targets only computer screens, skipping that would work on all media types. Depends on the requirement. Both work on a screen.